# Prevent opening Contextual ActionBar when selecting text in textview

Tags: android, textview, cab, onselect

in my app , I have a textview which is selectable.
I want to let user select text and with a pressing a button , highlight it but the CAB would open automatically while in my context , CAB and it's functionality does not make sense

Also I need actionbar itself so I don't want to use theme like Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar

Additionally, Defining ActionMode.Callback and set it as a Custom Selection ActionMode Callback for textview and then returning false from its function cause the textview loose its selectablity function ( what exactly happened is that the text selected and unselected in glimpse)

What should I do to get rid of CAB in my case?

Comment: well,as far as my tries and searches are gone ,it seems CAB and selection in Edittext and textview are tightly coupled and there is no way to get rid of it...